# Android ExampleInstrumentedTest failing for flavors

Tags: android, testing, junit, junit4, android-productflavors

I'm working on test Android app, default PackageName is `com.kagarlickij.myapplication`

My 'development' and 'staging' productFlavors add applicationIdSuffix, so PackageName for staging app is `com.kagarlickij.myapplication.**staging**`

When I run `./gradlew connectedStagingDebugAndroidTest` I'm getting this exception:

```
    > Task :app:connectedStagingDebugAndroidTest
Starting 1 tests on Nexus_5X_API_27(AVD) - 8.1.0

com.kagarlickij.myapplication.ExampleInstrumentedTest > useAppContext[Nexus_5X_API_27(AVD) - 8.1.0] FAILED 
        org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<...lickij.myapplication[]> but was:<...lickij.myapplication[.staging]>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:connectedStagingDebugAndroidTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/kagarlickij/Repos/public/MyApplication/app/build/reports/androidTests/connected/flavors/STAGING/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
50 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 43 up-to-date
```

Default *ExampleInstrumentedTest.java*:

```
package com.kagarlickij.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 * Instrumented test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * @see <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing">Testing documentation</a>
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    public void useAppContext() throws Exception {
        // Context of the app under test.
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

        assertEquals("com.kagarlickij.myapplication", appContext.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

build.gradle - https://github.com/kagarlickij/MyApplication/blob/dev/0.4.0/app/build.gradle

How *ExampleInstrumentedTest.java* can be changed to support `PackageNames` from flavors?

Comment: share gradle file

Comment: @Omi , it's https://github.com/kagarlickij/MyApplication/blob/dev/0.4.0/app/build.gradle

Comment: try with remove **testImplementation** 3 lines from gradle file then clean and rebuild..

Comment: I did (http://prntscr.com/hmvts7), but test failed with new exceptions - https://gist.github.com/kagarlickij/9c880cef9df60bf4cfd57cab8edc8b0b

Comment: ok revert changes try another way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the flavor name to your test, something like:

```
assertEquals("com.kagarlickij.myapplication." + BuildConfig.FLAVOR , appContext.getPackageName());
```

OR:

```
assertEquals(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, appContext.getPackageName());
```